# J48 running in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, j48, rweka

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
data (iris)

### 18 sub datasets
  N<-18
  iris_dataset<-list()
    for (i in 1:N) {iris_dataset[[i]]<-iris[sample(1:10, 1):sample(75:150, 1),]}


  j48_c.models <-list()
  cl<-makeCluster(8)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  j48_c.models<-foreach(i=1:N, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
    library (RWeka)
    J48(Species ~ ., data = iris_dataset[[i]], control = Weka_control(M = 30, C = 0.05)) }

  stopCluster(cl)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

I would like to create in parallel models (J48). So that a model will be built for each sub dataset. For instance, for `iris_dataset[[1]]` the J48 will be `j48_c.models[[1]]` ... and for `iris_dataset[[18]]` the J48 will be `j48_c.models[[18]]`.

You can run the models in the following way individually:

```
> model<-J48(Species ~ ., data = iris_dataset[[1]], control = Weka_control(M = 30, C = 0.05))
> model
J48 pruned tree
------------------

Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (46.0)
Petal.Width > 0.6
|   Petal.Width <= 1.7: versicolor (54.0/5.0)
|   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (36.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     3

Size of the tree :  5
```